# Colouring squares in a grid

Tags: combinatorics

It is proposed to colour the squares of a $4 \times 4$ board black and white, so that there are exactly two black squares and two white squares in each row or column. [image]

In how many ways can this be done?

I've tried this finding out the number of ways column 1 and 2 can be done which is $36 = 6 \cdot 6$ as $\binom{4}{2}$ since the second column doesn't get in the way of the first.

Then I hit a road block. Can anyone provide a hint?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A001499](https://oeis.org/A001499).

Comment: Please see https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2018/04/01/a-collection-of-binary-grid-counting-problems/ and http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~r1pan/problems/p19.html for explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ad-hoc low level solution can be quickly given. There are $6$ possibilities to fill in the first row. Fix now a solution grid. After applying the one shuffle permutation of columns that map the first, resp. second black square of the first row to the positions 1, 2 of this first row, we get a "special grid". (The shuffle does not change the order of the black and/or white squares of the first line.)

The number of all solution grids is then the number of realizations

```
XX
????
????
????    times 6 .
```

The next reduction is to move in the first column the second occurence of a "black square " `X` to the upper most possible position. There are only three possibilities for the `X`, so we count realizations like

```
XX
X???
????
????    times 6 times 3 .
```

Now let us take a closer look to the second column. The `X` is either at position $(2,2)$, and we can fill in the picture in exactly one way, or not, then... (we either norm the second column with an `X` at position $(2,3)$, taking the number times two, a.s.o., or we count the four possibilities in an other way.) We get as answer

```
[ XX        ( XX           ) ]
[ XX        ( X ??         ) ]
[   XX      (  X??         ) ]
[   XX plus (   ?? times 2 ) ]  times 6 times 3 .
```

There are thus $(1+2\cdot 2)\cdot 6\cdot 3=90$ solution grids.

Code checking this:

```
sage: J = [0,1]
....: rows = [ [a,b,c,d] for a in J for b in J for c in J for d in J if a+b+c+d == 2 ]
....: tables = [ matrix( ZZ, 4, 4, [r1, r2, r3, r4] )
....:            for r1 in rows for r2 in rows for r3 in rows for r4 in rows ]
....: tables = [ A for A in tables
....:            if  sum( A[:,0].list() ) == 2
....:            and sum( A[:,1].list() ) == 2
....:            and sum( A[:,2].list() ) == 2
....:            and sum( A[:,3].list() ) == 2 ]
....: 
sage: len(tables)
90
```